# How does the FED calculate SAAR for GDP?

Tags: time-series

In looking at the Fed's GDP growth rate data, it looks like the fed uses a different calculation for calculating annualized growth rate than the typical annualized rate of change. Does anyone have any insight or link to resources where the fed explains its methodology in calculating SAAR?

Thank you!!

Comment: Does this help ? https://www.fool.com/knowledge-center/how-to-calculate-the-annual-growth-rate-for-real-g.aspx

Comment: unfortunately not

Comment: How are you calculating it The formula in Step 2 of the @AlexC's link is precisely how BEA calculates SAAR.

Comment: An example where your calculation differs from the official BEA figure might be useful. Otherwise it is "not clear what you are asking".